# pdfbox: add background color or highlight the text added using contentStream.showText

Tags: pdfbox

I am modifying a pdf by adding some text data. I would like to put a yellow background or highlight to the added text. I am using contentStream.showText(). Is it possible ? I thought there is some setBackGroundColor for text. Seems like its not there. I could do it by adding rectangle. Looking for some more clean implementation

Any help is really appreciated!
Prem

Comment: Adding a rectangle and filling it is the way to go.

Comment: And do that *before* adding the text, not thereafter... (we've had the funniest questions already... ;))